# Custom Order Received endpoint when switching Subscriptions

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I have set 3 types of subscriptions which are Grouped products. I show a Form on my order-received (Thank you) page in WooCommerce. The thing is, when someone downgrades/upgrades subscription, he can fill the form again with different order number.
I tried to use this code to redirect to my-account if someone switches subscription plan

```html
add_filter('woocommerce_thankyou', 'redirect_if_switch_subscription');
function redirect_if_switch_subscription( $order_id ) {
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $url = '/my-account/';
    if ( $is_switched = order_contains_subscription($order_id) ) {
        return $url;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following (untested):

```
add_filter('template_redirect', 'order_received_redirect_if_switch_subscription');
function order_received_redirect_if_switch_subscription( $order_id ) {
    // Only on "Order received" page
    if( is_wc_endpoint_url('order-received') ) {
        global $wp;

        $order_id = absint( $wp->query_vars['order-received'] );
        $order    = wc_get_order($order_id);

        $subscriptions = wcs_order_contains_subscription( $order );

        if ( sizeof($subscriptions) > 0 ) {
            wp_redirect( get_permalink( get_option('woocommerce_myaccount_page_id') ) );
            exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It could works.